# Handle execution role to Setup SageMaker Domain (not root user)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-roles

I'm working on an AWS account managed by another team which use it only for S3 storage. We have authorization to use sagemaker, and administartor said “AmazonSageMakerFullAccess” have been given to me.
I'm trying to access sagemaker studio, for that I'm ask to "Setup SageMaker Domain" by aws. 
I then need a "Default execution role"
If I try to create one, I got error "User ... is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: ..."

There is an option to use a custom exiting one with the format
"arn:aws:iam::YourAccountID:role/yourRole" 
but while I have an account Id, I don't know what role to use. 
I don't have permission to create role, and the ones I see in IAM service doesn't seem to be related to sagemaker (also I don't have permission to see the details of those roles).

Should the sagemaker setup be done by the administrator who can create a new role ? Or is there a way for me to do it, and if so where can I find the role I need ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't attach any role to AWS SageMaker, and when you try to create SageMaker resource the very first time it will create a default execution role for the service. Either get the permission to create a role or ask your administrator to create a execution role for your SageMaker so that next time when you create one you can use the same role.